# How to create large tiles for Phone and messaging app?

Tags: 8.0, tiles

I have a new Lumia phone running Windows phone 8. This is supposed to be a PHONE and I am supposed to be able to send TEXTS. Where were the large icons for these activities?

I could find candy crush and similar things but I could not find a similar sized icon for the phone?

Comment: You want to have a large sized tile for phone and messaging in the start screen. Am I right?

Comment: @PhilCutler This is not a place to provide feedback or criticize. This site is **not linked with Microsoft**. If you want to place a feedback contact Microsoft or use the feedback app .This is a **question answer site** where users ask questions about **actual problems they face**. For more details on how to use this site see [here](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @PhilCutler I answered your question. Please, consider improving your question (using the edit button): simply state the problem you are facing and remove your personal opinions; I can understand you are frustrated by your problem, asking for help is the right thing to do, but the tone of your question is not helping at all. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

You can **add** tiles and **set the size** of your favorite apps to the start screen by following [these simple instruction](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/move-or-unpin-a-tile-on-start).

**Add** a new tile:

[image]

**Resize** a tile:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, particularly those gifs. I would consider using gifs in furture. They are useful.